# Creating table with phpMyAdmin, missing BINARY type

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, dreamhost

I'm using phpMyAdmin on a DreamHost server to create a database schema, and the dropdown list of column types lists VARCHAR, BLOB, TINYBLOB, LONGBLOB, etc., but I don't see BINARY. Is there a reason BINARY is missing? Could/should I just create/edit the table via SQL script to get a BINARY column?

**Edit:** Furthermore, when I try to create a TINYBLOB column and specify a length, the generated script *doesn't* contain that length *and* MySQL reports an error because it expects a length to be specified! (I see now it's probably because I've indexed the column and need to be able to specify a length for the key)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the latest version of PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: How? This is built into DreamHost. They're at 3.3.10.4.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested with phpMyAdmin 3.3.10.4 and BINARY is listed in the choices. This comes from $cfg['ColumnTypes'] and maybe someone at DreamHost removed this choice.